# How can right align icon in Menu of Blazor App?

Tags: css, blazor, blazor-server-side

I want add a right icon to Menu:

My code using `float: right` but it not working:

```
<li class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" @onclick="() => TogleSubmenu(NavSubmenu.Second)">               
                Upload <img src="../images/upicon.png"  style="float: right; height: 10px; width: 15px;">
            </NavLink>
 </li>
```

Result:

[image]

How can right align icon in Menu of Blazor App?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are using flexbox, so, just use justify-content to align your items to the side. 
Add `justify-content: space-between` to `.nav-link`, and it should work.

Comment: add justify-content: flex-end; it will right all text "Upload" and Icon, I only want right icon.

Comment: Completely my bad. I didn't see you wanted the icon specifically. I updated my question, I hope this way works @DT